# How can use the Process class of Pythons Multiprocessing library to run a function multiple times?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, arguments

I've got a function that simulates a stochastic system of chemical reactions. I now want to use the Process class from Pythons Multiprocessing library to run the stochastic simulation function several times.

I tried the following:

```
v = range(1, 51)
def parallelfunc(v):     
    gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.utcnow()
    p = Process(target=parallelfunc, args=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50))
    p.start()    
    p.join()
    end = datetime.utcnow()
    sim_time = end - start
    print(f"Simualtion utc time:\n{sim_time}")
```

but this results in the error `TypeError: parallelfunc() takes 1 positional argument but 50 were given`

Then i tried just passing `range(1, 51)` to both `parallelfunc` and the `args` parameter of process but then I just get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the deceleration of `parallelfunc`

The method of using a function like `parallelfunc` in this way works when using `pool.map` there I just pass `parallelfunc` followed by a list from 1 - 50.

But I can't figure out whats going wrong here.

Any suggestions
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats cause you have given too many arguments.
try

```
def parallelfunc(*v):     
     gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)
```

this allows you to take multiple arguments

Comment: you can use ** instead of * if you want to

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because your are giving 50 parameters as arguments for the parallelfunc, which you defined it to be only one argument. Maybe try adding list() so it is only one argument, which contains the 50 numbers. However, I dont know if the number of numbers is high.